# UITableView crashing on scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

This is the code i have:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        //self.tableView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *wood = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood_pattern.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = wood;
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60;
}
```

When i scroll down and then back up to a cell which was previously on screen, the app crashes. Any ideas why?

On a side note.. the background color is set to red, and although i can see the text, I can't see the background color.

Comment: When developers see crash we usually look for what Crash log says. Without Crash log its waste of our time trying to figure out by looking at code. Can you please show us crash log.

Comment: Set the cell color outside the if statement and you should see the red color, but I need to see the error for further help

Comment: I'm having continuous problems with xcode acting weird (non-bold nslogs, suggesting the least likely completions for my code, jumping up and down when i type, unticking the target box by itself every time i try and add a file etc.) and right now it's not giving me crash logs.

Comment: about the background color: you want to change the background color of the content view

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] as suggested by vikingsosegundo but otherwise your code looks fine

Comment: When scrolling, several dataSource/delegate methods will be called.

My bet: in tabelView:numberOfRowInSection: you are accessing a collection  — array or similar — that got over-released/under-retained.

Comment: Great, thanks. All i can get out of xcode is that it's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Nothing is showing up in the Debugging area.

Comment: Everything is standard. I literally have only changed what you see above, and in the other areas i changed it to return 1 on number of sections, and to return 3 on number of cells in section.

Comment: Yes. I've posted everything I have now.

Comment: On the contentview.. i changed it to that. Now it shows the red right before my label starts, and right after my label ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind UITableView properly in XIB. and right following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```