# How is my implemention of UITableViewController wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This code copied anywhere else seems to work. It's just inside my app where it crashes. Any ideas why?

another .m...

```
#import "JEntryTableViewController.h"
@interface JCreateViewController () {

    JEntryTableViewController *_tableView;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) JEntryTableViewController *tableView;

@end

@implementation JCreateViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.tableView = [[JEntryTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView.view];

    }
    return self;
}
```

JEntryTableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface JEntryTableViewController : UITableViewController {

}

@end
```

JEntryTableViewController.m:

```
#import "JEntryTableViewController.h"

@interface JEntryTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation JEntryTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CountryCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60;
}

@end
```

I ran this as a quick test to make sure it was set up right, and to my surprise, when i scroll back to a cell I've already seen, it crashes and gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Unfortunately the debugging area isn't giving me anything back that I can work with, and i really don't know what the problem is - it's such a basic, simple bunch of code. I don't know what to fix. It should work.

Comment: Add an nslog to each section of code in the .m, and see which ones are called

Comment: I just did this. It called all of the relevant bits, and then i scrolled, and it didn't call anything additional before it's crash.

Comment: possible double-post of [UITableView crashing on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661060/uitableview-crashing-on-scroll)

Comment: You have to set the delegate and datasource for the tableview

Comment: try changing @interface JEntryTableViewController :UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{

} and connect both data source and delegate to the table view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You way to implement the tableView may not the usual way we often do.

You can add the tableView directly into a ViewController without using another viewController inherit from UITableViewController.

What you should do is identically as what you did in JEntryTableViewController.

When come to the EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem, there are several solutions to find the exact problem.
1. [EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

2. at the right section of Xcode [image: break points]  you can add these kind of break points, it may help you find the exception quickly in your case.

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. write `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` in
   `JEntryTableViewController.h` file
2. write down the crash log here so that we can easily solve your problem.